# Why does my choice of Style disrupt Numbering?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

I am using Word 2016. The screenshot displays my 2 Styles (defined via `Home > Styles`): Style 1 in black Times New Roman, and Style  2 for red Arial.

I applied Style 2 to F, but the numbering ought've continued (F ought've been numbered '5' instead of '2'). So I right-clicked on '2' and then left-clicked on 'Continue Numbering', but '2' still failed to change to '5'.

Comment: What happens if you choose all items and re-apply numbering?

Comment: @harrymc I was hoping avert this, especially if I have a long document.

Comment: Do you use numbering for headers (which are separated from each other with blocks of normal text) or are you using numbering on a list of items, each one is followed directly in the next line? see http://i.imgur.com/U92Xg0q.jpg and tell us so someone may give you the solution you seek or yet an efficient way to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using MS Word 2013 and it appears to have all the the options you mentioned in your problem. I am having trouble replicating the error you had, but i think I might know what the issue is. Check the options you have selected in the Manage Styles menu: `Home > Styles > Manage Styles`. Is 'Style based on': set to 'List paragraph'? If it is not try that. If you are still getting the error then check the format for numbering: `Home > Styles > Manage Styles > Formatting > Numbering` and see if you accidentally set a limit to numbering lists.

While tedious, if nothing else you can right-click on the line you want numbered and left-click 'Set Numbering Value', and tell it to continue numbering , or manually set the value for that number. Hope this helps.